# Wait for a thread before render widget android

Tags: android, multithreading, singleton

folks, lets suppose I have two activities, A and B. Activity A is in charge to span a thread to get some json (a list of countries for example) from a rest service which must then be cached in a var called for example countries in a Singleton object. Which then will be retrieved from Activity B to fill a Spinner widget in B UI. What is happening currently in my code is that var countries in the Singleton object is returning null. Seems as there was no time enough to get the data from the backend. So, which do you think is the best way to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), retrieve values in `doInBackground()` and display then in `onPostExecute()`

In `onPostExecute()` you can put the values into your singleton and call `startActivity()` starting B.

Comment: Thanks Alex!, your answer sounds OK. Is just I'm used to using Threads, more than AsyncTasks.